# MongoDB can't find records with specific number for variable

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express

When I try find records with specific value for one variable in MongoDB directly, it is found with no problem.
`{defCordX: 15}`
https://puu.sh/GV5jr/e3362cacfd.png

But when I do the same filter in my express app, it returns empty array

```
const findReportsVillage = Reports 
  .find({defCordX: 15})
  findReportsVillage.exec((err, data) => {
  console.log(data);
  res.render('index', { title: 'Reports', data, searchVillage });
  });
```

Can someone tell me why this is happen?

Comment: a guess; does `Reports.find({defCordX: 15})` return a promise? so maybe try with `await` or `.then` and see if that fixes it.

Comment: no promises there. But I have the same code looking for variable which is string and it works just well. So for me it looks like problem with find variable which is number type